# Основы JS - Как вывести только одно сообщение после окончания цикла?

Tags: javascript

В общем есть такая игра в которой нужно угадать слово по буквам (виселица). Она работает, всё ок, но есть определённое количество попыток ввода и они исчерпаются при каждом вводе буквы, как правильном так и неправильном. Как сделать чтобы при вводе неправильной буквы выводился алерт с сообщением "такой буквы нету" и в этом случае отнималось количество попыток, только когда угадал букву попытки остаются? Перепробовал множество способов чтобы вывести сообщение, делал с помощью else но мне выводит алерт "такой буквы нет" каждый раз когда цикл проходит круг и если такая буква найдется в слове 5й буквой то мне выведет 5 раз подряд сообщение и отнимет 5 попыток ввода (при том что ввел только 1 букву).

```
let words = ["лес", "сок", "кот", "дом", "ход", "сад"];
let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let answer = [];

for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answer[i] = "_";
}

let remainingLetters = word.length;
let tries = 5; // Количество попыток

while (remainingLetters > 0 && tries > 0) {
    console.log(word); // Подсветка слова в консоле
    alert("Текущее состояние игры! " + answer.join(" "));

    let guess = prompt("Введите 1 букву! У вас осталось попыток: " + tries);
    if (guess === null) {
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
        alert("Пожалуйста введите только 1 букву");
    } else {
        tries--; // Отнимаем попытку
        for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if (word[j] === guess && answer[j] === "_") {
                answer[j] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;
            } 
        }
    }
}

if (remainingLetters === 0) {
    alert("Поздавляем! Вы отгадали слово " + word);
} else if (tries === 0){
    alert("У вас закончились попытки! Вы проиграли");
} else {
    alert("Жаль что вы покинули игру");
}
```

Comment: отнимать `tries--;` только если буквы нет, а не всегда

Comment: Да, я знаю что tries--; я поставил не там, я не знал что с ним делать чтобы он работал только когда буквы нет! Флаг это супер, то что нужно и сообщение тоже вывел! Спасибо большое, Виталий!

Comment: всегда пожалуйста, удачи вам в изучении :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let words = ["лес", "сок", "кот", "дом", "ход", "сад"];
let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
let answer = [];

for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    answer[i] = "_";
}

let remainingLetters = word.length;
let tries = 5; // Количество попыток

while (remainingLetters > 0 && tries > 0) {
    console.log(word); // Подсветка слова в консоле
    alert("Текущее состояние игры! " + answer.join(" "));

    let guess = prompt("Введите 1 букву! У вас осталось попыток: " + tries);
    if (guess === null) {
        break;
    } else if (guess.length !== 1) {
        alert("Пожалуйста введите только 1 букву");
    } else {
        let flag = false; // делаем фдаг для проверки
        for (let j = 0; j < word.length; j++) {
            if (word[j] === guess && answer[j] === "_") {
                answer[j] = guess;
                remainingLetters--;
                flag = true; // если букву нашли, то включаем флаг
            } 
        }
        if (!flag) tries--; // Отнимаем попытку
    }
}

if (remainingLetters === 0) {
    alert("Поздавляем! Вы отгадали слово " + word);
} else if (tries === 0){
    alert("У вас закончились попытки! Вы проиграли");
} else {
    alert("Жаль что вы покинули игру");
}
```